# R get string of unique vales from Titanic

Tags: r

this question came from my shiny app where I tried to use reactive property for cascade params,  for first step I created hard coded string  ***s*** which works OK, 
and now I'm trying to add dynamics to my code producing this string dynamically and this doesn't work, i'm bit lost in all those types of object in R probably...
So, s works OK, I assume s is just a vector with chars element:

```
> s <- c("1st","2nd","3rd","Crew")
> str(s)
 chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
```

And now I'm trying to get same type of string but using code:

```
t <-  unique(data.frame(Titanic)$Class) ## use data.frame to make Nams available.
str(t)            ## now it's factor and looks like I need chr
t2 <- lapply(t, as.character)
str(t2)            ##  this loook like chr now
List of 4
$ : chr "1st"
$ : chr "2nd"
$ : chr "3rd"
$ : chr "Crew"
```

So using that t2 intead of my hand made s produce error (dimentions....), I don't understand whay it's like this, looks like t2 structure should be OK ?
Tx for help
Mario

Comment: Don't use `lapply`. Just use `t2 <-as.character(t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector you are looking for is actually part of the `dimnames` attribute of the data set.  In this case, it is simply the row names.

```
rownames(Titanic)
# [1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "Crew"
```

To continue with what you were doing - `data.frame(Titanic)$Class` returns a factor vector.  We can use `levels()` to get the values we want, which in this case is also the unique values (as is the same for all cases that don't include `NA`).

```
levels(data.frame(Titanic)$Class)
# [1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "Crew"
```

Comment: Tx, Richard !!!            _levels(data.frame(Titanic)$Class)_ this solved all, I just need to add dynamics to $ColumnName,  i  tried to use _temp <- quote("Class")      then   levels(data.frame(Titanic$eval(temp))_ and it didn't work.

Comment: And thanks MrFlick, sorry you solution was so laconic, didn't see it at first .Best.m